# How to use morphMany with a custom function in a model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

(This is about Laravel 5.8)
I know you can create custom functions in your model, but I can't figure out how to make a custom function that uses data from the function morphMany.

What works:
*model.php:*

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Image', 'owner');
}
```

*page.blade.php:*

```
@foreach($model->images() as $image)
    {{ $image->url }}
@endforeach
```

This works. But I want to create a function that for example only gives the poster back. But when I place that foreach in a function inside my model. It won't loop trough the images. See the following code:
What doesn't work:
*model.php:*

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Image', 'owner');
}

public function poster()
{
    $images = $this->morphMany('App\Image', 'owner');

    foreach($images as $image)
    {
        /* THIS CODE WILL NEVER RUN SOMEHOW */
        if ($image->type == "poster")
        {
            return $image;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The code just returns NULL, what am I missing?

Comment: You forgot to open a `{` after the foreach

Comment: @dparoli oh oops.. I'll edit the example code. That was not the error is was getting ;)  but nice job finding that one :)

Answer (score 0):

You would like to use the accessor `$model->images` that returns a collection instead of the query constructor `$model->images()` that returns a query builder, i.e:

```
//page.blade.php
@foreach($model->images as $image)
    {{ $image->url }}
@endforeach

// in Model    
public function poster()
{ 
    foreach($this->images as $image)
    {
        if ($image->type == "poster")
        {
            return $image;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit my answer, this is what I want really answer, try the code and see what you get